Best practices to install binaries inside nix-shell
I'm preparing a Nix derivation for tenv version manager.
Steps nix-build and nix-shell work fine, I can run tenv inside the nix-shell.
But the purpose of tenv is installing needed versions of binaries Terraform, Terragrunt, and so on.
My question is: what is the best practice for storing these binaries?
If I understand correctly we shouldn't store something inside /nix/store
For now, I wrote it like this:
    src = fetchurl {
        url = "https://github.com/tofuutils/tenv/releases/download/v1.9.4/tenv_v1.9.4_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz";
        sha256 = "b12491f9ac61e5abfc64b716a9020aacc67ff873f3f01d6cc7175d945a7d2a4c";
    };

    nativeBuildInputs = [ makeWrapper ];
    buildInputs = [ bash ];

    installPhase = ''
      mkdir -p $out/bin
      tar xzvf $src -C $out/bin
    '';

    postFixup = ''
      wrapProgram $out/bin/tenv \
        --prefix PATH : ${lib.makeBinPath buildInputs} \
        --set TENV_ROOT /tmp
    '';

Please check the full MR here https://github.com/tofuutils/tenv-nix/pull/2/files
